# performSegueWithIdentifier not working after Signup with Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm using `performSegueWithIdentifier` and everything is OK on all of them, but there is one that doesnt work at all.

I'm using Parse.com to signup a user and I want to perform a segue after they sigup, but I can't get it to work. I think the performSegue should be place at function `signUpViewController`

[image]

My code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI
import Bolts
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKShareKit
import CoreLocation

struct localizacaoActualizada {

static var rua = ""
static var localidade = ""
static var codigopostal = ""
static var giropostal = ""
static var country = ""


}


class ViewController: UIViewController, ENSideMenuDelegate, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {



var logInViewController: PFLogInViewController! = PFLogInViewController()
var signUpViewController: PFSignUpViewController! = PFSignUpViewController()

var localidadeActual = ""

@IBOutlet weak var userLogedIn: UILabel!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.sideMenuController()?.sideMenu?.delegate = self

    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()



    // Se ta loggado
    var user = PFUser.currentUser()


    if (user?.username != nil) {



      //  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("aposLogin", sender: self)


    }



}


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    var user = PFUser.currentUser()
    self.userLogedIn.text = user?.username




     if (user?.username == nil) {

        self.logInViewController.fields = ( PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFields.LogInButton | PFLogInFields.SignUpButton | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten | PFLogInFields.DismissButton )

        //PFLogInFields.Facebook




        var logInLogoTitle = UILabel()
        logInLogoTitle.text = "ParaFora"

        var SignUpLogoTitle = UILabel()
        SignUpLogoTitle.text = "ParaFora"

        //self.logInViewController.facebookPermissions = [ "friends_about_me" ]
        self.logInViewController.logInView!.logo = logInLogoTitle
        self.logInViewController.delegate = self
        self.signUpViewController.signUpView!.logo = SignUpLogoTitle
        self.signUpViewController.delegate = self
        self.logInViewController.signUpController = self.signUpViewController

    }

     else {

        //Tentativa 1
        //self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        var user = PFUser.currentUser()
        user?["localidade"] = localidadeActual
        user?.saveInBackground()



        //tentativa 2

        //var user = PFUser.currentUser()
        //var idUser = user?["objectId"] as! String
       // println("O id do utilizador actual:" + idUser)

       // var query = PFQuery(className:"User")
       // query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(idUser) {
       //     (User: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
       //     if error != nil {
       //         println(error)
       //     } else if let User = User {
      //          println("Tentativa de escrever" + self.localidadeActual + "no servidor")
      //          User["localidade"] = self.localidadeActual
      //          User.saveInBackground()
     //           println("done?")
     //       }
       // }
        //



   // self.performSegueWithIdentifier("aposLogin", sender: self)
    }
}

//Localizacao

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)
{

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

        if (error != nil)
        {
            println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if placemarks.count > 0
        {
            let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
            self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
        }
        else
        {
            println("Error with the data.")
        }
    })
}


func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark)
{
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    //self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    println(placemark.locality)
    println(placemark.postalCode)
    println(placemark.administrativeArea)
    println(placemark.country)
    println(placemark.location)
    println(placemark.administrativeArea)
    println(placemark.subAdministrativeArea)

//        println(placemark.addressDictionary)
  //      println(placemark.areasOfInterest)

    localidadeActual = placemark.locality
    localizacaoActualizada.rua = placemark.name
    localizacaoActualizada.localidade = placemark.locality

    //Guarda o codigo postal na estrutura
    if count(placemark.postalCode) > 4{
    localizacaoActualizada.codigopostal = placemark.postalCode.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: advance(placemark.postalCode.startIndex, 0), end: advance(placemark.postalCode.endIndex, -3)))
    localizacaoActualizada.giropostal = placemark.postalCode.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: advance(placemark.postalCode.startIndex, 4), end: advance(placemark.postalCode.endIndex, 0)))

    }

    else {
        localizacaoActualizada.codigopostal = placemark.postalCode
    }





    // Obtem a localidade no serv


    var user = PFUser.currentUser()
    println(user?["localidade"])
    //fim obter localidade

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!)
{
    println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
}

//fim local


// MARK: Parse Login

func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, shouldBeginLogInWithUsername username: String, password: String) -> Bool {


    if (!username.isEmpty || !password.isEmpty) {
        return true
    }else {
        return false
    }

}



func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, didLogInUser user: PFUser) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("aposLogin", sender: self)


}

func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, didFailToLogInWithError error: NSError?) {
    println("Failed to login...")
}

func logInViewControllerDidCancelLogIn(logInController: PFLogInViewController) {

}

// MARK: Parse Signup

func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController, didSignUpUser user: PFUser) {


    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("setupCliente", sender:self)


}
func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController, didFailToSignUpWithError error: NSError?) {

    println("FAiled to sign up...")

}



func signUpViewControllerDidCancelSignUp(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController) {

    println("User dismissed sign up.")

}

// MARK: Actions

@IBAction func simpleAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.presentViewController(self.logInViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}



@IBAction func logoutAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    PFUser.logOut()

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func toggleSideMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
    toggleSideMenuView()
}

// MARK: - ENSideMenu Delegate
func sideMenuWillOpen() {
    println("sideMenuWillOpen")
}

func sideMenuWillClose() {
    println("sideMenuWillClose")
}

func sideMenuShouldOpenSideMenu() -> Bool {
    println("sideMenuShouldOpenSideMenu")
    return true
}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that the  signUpViewController-method gets called?

Comment: Yes its called because it dismiss the viewcontroller and I have checked with debugger.

Answer (score 0):

In your signUpViewController function you are dismissing the current view controller and then you are calling performSegueWithIdentifier with the sender as the view controller you just dismissed. Try removing the dismissViewControllerAnimated method call

Comment: Already tried, no success. I have something similar that is working: `logInViewController`. But for signup it doesnt work =/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But I managed to solve it, although it is not a perfect solution.

What I did was to dismiss the `PFSignUpViewController`.

But before I did that I set a global variable, a bool called `initialSignUp` in my case to true. Once the controller was dismissed I checked in the `PFLogInViewController`'s `viewDidAppear()` method if `initialSignUp` was true. 
If this was the case I changed it back to false and then performed the segue.

This workaround works for me and I hope I could help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the delegate of the loginViewController's signupViewController. Something like this (sorry it's in swift, but you can propably work it out):

```
 let loginViewController = LoginViewController() 
 loginViewController.delegate = self
 loginViewController.signUpController?.delegate = self
```

and then, you can call the following methods to dismiss the view and perform the segue (or anything else).

```
func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, didLogInUser user: PFUser) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueID")

}
func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController, didSignUpUser user: PFUser) -> Void {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueID")
}
```

Hope this help. It worked for me.

Cheers,
Julien